# Angular6 - Wait for subscribe to finish

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-httpclient

I have a component, and the method in the service is :

```
getResults(option:any) {
    //forming the url and patchModel
    return this.http.patch(url,patchModel,option);
}
```

And the component file looks like:

```
onClickMenu(option: any): void {  //function doesnt return anything
    this.service.getResults(option).subscribe(result => {
        this.menu = result.menu;
    });
}
```

Now i am getting the right value, but i have other methods following onClickMenu in the typescript file that get executed before this.menu get populated. Since the value in this.menu is need in other methods, it is failing to execute. I want to wait till this.menu gets the right value.

How can I do that **without async/Promise**? I am keen on using observable.

Comment: Add another line in the subscribe call back and call that code that you want to execute once you have a `menu` instance.

Comment: That is not possible since, the result goes to the HTML file which calls another method which needs the right value of 'this.menu'. I need a way to wait till the right value is fetched by this.menu.

Answer (score 0):

The "function(s)" that are being called before `this.menu` get populated should be called from inside the finally block... check my comment in the call below

```
this.service.getResults(option).subscribe(
    result => { this.menu = result.menu; }
    () => { /* call your function(s) here... inside the finally block */}
);
```

this finally block will executed after the `this.menu = result.menu` finishes and you got your updated menu.